# Expression Engine Decryption of form settings failed

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, expressionengine

I am having a problem in submitting channel form from the frontend of my website.
I am getting the Below error

**The form you submitted contained the following errors**

```
*Decryption of form settings failed.*
```

**When I force query string in my website url .Everything works fine.**

Please suggest the fix for this